# Installing Apache Airflow on Windows 11 with Docker, but container exiting

Tags: installation, airflow, docker-desktop, windows-11

I followed these steps to set up Airflow in Docker Desktop:

- ran `docker pull apache/airflow:latest` on command prompt
- created a folder to store Airflow configurations and DAGs, e.g., `C:\airflow`
- executed `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v %cd%:/opt/airflow apache/airflow:latest` to start the Airflow Docker container

Looking at the logs for the container in Docker Desktop, it immediately exited with the message:

> airflow command error: the following arguments are required: GROUP_OR_COMMAND

Does anybody know why the container doesn't start? How can the command error be fixed?

I also tried to install Apache Airflow without Docker using pip, initializing Airflow database, creating an admin user, but Airflow webserver doesn´t start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the message, it seems like you need to add a command to start the airflow service in the container. I imagine it is running `airflow` without specifying a command. For example, to start the webserver, it would need to run `airflow webserver`. [Checking the image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/airflow/latest/images/sha256-4c04bdbb4288846c23c80e1dda7059b6ca6ad288afd9422bbc86ccc535431fa1?context=explore) in Dockerhub, that appears to be accurate.

*However*, even if you get the container up, it will still not work, because Airflow requires a back end database to communicate with & multiple other components. I recommend following [this guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#fetching-docker-compose-yaml) to set up a local environment for Airflow using Docker. This guide uses Docker compose, which will initialize all the components for a working Airflow installation (You can see how complex it can become by viewing their [compose yaml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.7.2/docker-compose.yaml)).

Comment: Thanks, Jered! Your response encouraged me to take a deeper look into my own environment and discover a lot of missing software installations in my computer. On a side note for others, airflow requires the following prerequisites: 
♦Python: 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11
♦Databases:
-PostgreSQL: 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
-MySQL: 5.7, 8.0, 8.1
-SQLite: 3.15.0+
-MSSQL(Experimental): 2017, 2019
♦Kubernetes: 1.23, 1.24, 1.25, 1.26, 1.27